# Running multiple iterations of ArcMap model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, integration

I am working with a model that is build in modelbuilder and I have to test with with over 150 different use cases. Is there a way I could upload a table with use cases as it attribute and then have the model run one time on all the 150 cases, one by one. For instance, have it run the first time one case #1 and after is has finished run again at case #2 and so on. I know I have to use iteration but unfortunately it only runs ones.

Below is an image of the model:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dH7tuhA.png]

Answer (score 2):

You could either use an [iterator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000001n000000.htm) at the beginning of the model to change your inputs each time. So if you wanted to use a table, you could use iterate field values to loop over all the rows in your table and reference them using inline variable substitution.

Alternatively, you could create another model that calls your current one and has an iterator which will loop over the table. It's probably a little more difficult to implement, but might be easier to work with. See [Integrating a model within a model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007p000000).

Another option, that is implementable right now, would be to batch your model with all 150 inputs. Just like standard ArcMap tools, you can right click your model in Catalog and select `Batch...`